# Send Gravity Forms data to redirection page

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a very simple form created with Gravity Forms;

It submits two numbers and then redirects to a different result page.

How do I retrieve those two numbers on the result page?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter("gform_confirmation_4", "custom_confirmation", 3, 4 );
function custom_confirmation($confirmation, $form, $lead, $ajax)
```

Gives a custom confirmation. Each field value can be retrieved by using $lead[{field ID}]

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this based on using a combination of form submission hooks and the GForms API. It's a horrible plugin so I apologise for the messiness of the logic flow. It's important to use the framework methods rather than processing the data yourself since there are a good amount of hacks and shonky things going on in there to correctly match field IDs and so forth.

I will provide a solution to pass a submission from one form to pre-populate another. Changing the destination for POST data is pretty straightforward, they have an example for it on their `gform_form_tag` [hook documentation page](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_form_tag). Yes, that really is the only way of doing it.

Without further ado here is the code. I've set it up to work off form configuration to make things simpler for the end user, so it works like this:

- Select "allow field to be populated dynamically" in your destination form field's advanced settings and choose a parameter name for each.
- Add matching CSS classes on the source fields of the other form(s) to setup the associations.
- Add a CSS class to the source forms themselves so that we can quickly check if the redirection is necessary.

.

```
$class = 'GForms_Redirector';

add_filter('gform_pre_submission', array($class, 'checkForSubmissionRedirection'), 10, 1);
add_filter('gform_confirmation', array($class, 'performSubmissionRedirection'), 10, 4);

abstract class GForms_Redirector
{
    const SOURCE_FORMS_CLASS_MATCH = 'submission-redirect';
    const DEST_PAGE_SLUG = 'submit-page-slug';
    const DEST_FORM_ID = 1;

    protected static $submissionRedirectUrl;

    // first, read sent data and generate redirection URL
    function checkForSubmissionRedirection($form)
    {
        if (false !== preg_match('@\W' . self::SOURCE_FORMS_CLASS_MATCH . '\W@', $form['cssClass'])) {
            // load page for base redirect URL
            $destPage = get_page_by_path(self::DEST_PAGE_SLUG);

            // load form for reading destination form config
            $destForm = RGFormsModel::get_form_meta(self::DEST_FORM_ID, true);
            $destForm = RGFormsModel::add_default_properties($destForm);

            // generate submission data for this form (there seem to be no hooks before gform_confirmation that allow access to this. DUMB.)
            $formData = GFFormsModel::create_lead($form);

            // create a querystring for the new form based on mapping dynamic population parameters to CSS class names in source form
            $queryVars = array();
            foreach ($destForm['fields'] as $destField) {
                if (empty($destField['inputName'])) {
                    continue;
                }

                foreach ($form['fields'] as $field) {
                    if (preg_match('@(\s|^)' . preg_quote($destField['inputName'], '@') . '(\s|$)@', $field['cssClass'])) {
                        $queryVars[$destField['inputName']] = $formData[$field['id']];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // set the redirect URL to be used later
            self::$submissionRedirectUrl = get_permalink($destPage) . "?" . http_build_query($queryVars);
        }
    }

    // when we get to the confirmation step we set the redirect URL to forward on to
    function performSubmissionRedirection($confirmation, $form, $entry, $is_ajax = false)
    {
        if (self::$submissionRedirectUrl) {
            return array('redirect' => self::$submissionRedirectUrl);
        }

        return $confirmation;
    }
}
```

If you wanted to pass the form values someplace else via the querystring then you'd merely need to cut out my code from the callback and build your own URL to redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, now you can send it using a Query String on the confirmation settings.

They have the documentation on this link:
[How to send data from a form using confirmations](https://docs.gravityforms.com/using-confirmation-query-strings-to-populate-a-form-based-on-another-submission/#setting-up-the-first-form-to-send-data-using-confirmations)

Just follow the first step and it will be clear to you.

Comment: yes, but how about being able to POST data instead of using query string?